# What Chrome app APIs are currently available for mobile?

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, square-connect

I'm trying to make my own HTML5 POS using Square. My plan is to use Google's **chrome.*** APIs to handle a USB receipt printer and cash drawer. Square needs to be accessed via Java, which is what I am hoping to do by wrapping the Chrome app in an Apache Cordova container (if that's what they're even called) to make the app Android-compatible, also making them available to side-load on Chromebooks.

My biggest question is what **chrome.*** APIs are available on mobile these days? [The last update was apparently July 2014...](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/blob/master/docs/APIsAndLibraries.md) Please tell me there have been updates since then. Because if the **chrome.usb** API isn't available, I'm SOL and I'll basically need to rely on Java for Square's processing AND the receipt printer and cash drawer, and I don't know Java so that would be fun..not. Unless I'm missing something from Square's documentation on their API; perhaps it handles receipt printing and a cash drawer still. It didn't seem like it though.

Comment: Could you use the [Android Web API](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/web-api-android/)?

Comment: I could, yes. However, I'd like the app to work on as many devices as possible. I just want the flexibility. Android/iOS. Chrome would be a bonus.

Comment: I'm a little confused, Why does Square need to be accessed via Java?

Comment: To maintain PCI compliance. There's a second API called the Square Connect API I was thinking of using for refunds, but I don't think I'd be PCI compliant if I was sending requests over JavaScript.

Also, Square needs to be accessed via Java so I can accept payment with Square hardware. The Square Stand for iPads, the magstripe reader, and the chip/EMV/Android Pay/Apple Pay reader.

Comment: I'm not asking why Square, but why are you limited to Java? You said you wanted Android/iOS flexibility but it sounds like you are using the Android Register API?

Comment: Oh yeah. That's right. iOS doesn't use Java. Well, I really only plan on using Windows/ChromeOS/Android devices. Not a fan of Apple anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The instant you need to talk to hardware your options got very limited.

If you need to have the Android device talk to the printer & drawer that would be over USB and then you would have to write at least part of the app in Java or find/write a Cordova plug-in which will handle the USB side.

If Android is only a partial requirement: how about local webserver on a PC to control the receipt printer and cash drawer via USB with Android serving as a client (pure web app/progressive web app, hybrid, or pure Java).

For Chromebooks, you would need to see how well the external hardware (USB) interfaces work as I've heard mixed results.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I was initially thinking, but the language barrier is really a pain. I'd like to keep everything going through the main website. But the website isn't hosted here. I'm using a third party host. If I could, I'd be happy to set up the website at home/at the business location. Then I could have everything run over the same network, and perhaps use PHP.  Would learning a little bit of Java for Cordova be too pointless?

Comment: I'm thinking it's a good idea to set up a dedicated server just for that. Some it may seem odd to have a server that just prints receipts and opens drawers, having a full HTML5 front end means I can use it in any browser on any device then. Even Windows PCs. Are there any PHP libraries that can communicate with the printers over the network?

Comment: Sorry don't know, but if you are on a PC you've got more options although do keep in mind security/secure channels if this is for a commercial project as opposed to a hobby/demo. Nothing like picking a 'easy' library and finding out that its been hacked and you've got a screaming customer. Good luck.

Comment: I actually found another alternative solution. Instead of having a server open that I guess would neet to be protected by a firewall, what about Bluetooth? Cordova can use Bluetooth. So I can program everything in Chrome OS, and just use Cordova to give me the same experience on other devices with Bluetooth.

Although, this means that not all Windows computers would be able to function as a register, but what it DOES mean is that the business can be mobilized with Bluetooth receipt printers. There's just so many options lol.

Comment: I don't worry about security for Bluetooth either, considering that there will always be someone at the register when the business is open. Plus I could "hide" the actual printer at the POS so that customers can't just turn off the connection or change it.

Comment: ChromeOS bluetooth - I would advise testing - https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/4wk7tt/are_bluetooth_problems_with_chromeos_as/. As for security - I'm thinking of radio traffic sniffing. All I can say is to design & test with security in mind as you are dealing with purchase data.

Comment: Well...No rush. I'll come up with a solid decision in time. I'll just focus on the front end and see what works best.